# Salvaging the DFT questions and questions that fall unambiguously within our territory, from other sites

Tags: discussion, participation, site-promotion, other-se-sites

[We have a chat room](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/160/5) with a feed that tells us whenever a Matter Modeling question gets asked on a different SE site. It's nice to be able to easily see what all the Matter Modeling questions network-wide are, but the chat room's feed still doesn't help much with the more specific question of: Which *unanswered* Matter Modeling questions could be "salvaged" in some way to perhaps be migrated or re-asked here? We could make another chat room with a feed that only brings in the unanswered questions of a specific tag, but there will still be 1000+ questions that might benefit from some human pruning, so I have done that now here, **only including the questions that have not yet found their way to MMSE via [from-phys-se](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/from-phys-se) or [from-chem-se](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/from-chem-se)** (EST = electronic structure theory, DOS = density of states):

#### Physics.SE, with density-functional-theory tag, 0 upvoted or accepted answers:

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/530448/134583 (DFT-D: active 3 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/493114/134583 (EST: active on MMSE)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/329027/134583 (band structure: active 1 month ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255609/134583 (TD-DFT: [user](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=w0eP9esAAAAJ&hl=fi&oi=ao) active 5 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/542077/134583 (KS-DFT: but inactive, 3 months)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287873/134583 (HK Thm: user active ~25 days ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/531143/134583 (KS-DFT: user seen 5 days ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524771/134583 (DFT: [user](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=w0eP9esAAAAJ&hl=fi&oi=ao) seen 5 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524447/134583 (Basis sets: [user](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=w0eP9esAAAAJ&hl=fi&oi=ao) active 5 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/516484/134583 (pseudopotentials, seen 4 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515245/134583 (EST:  [user](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=w0eP9esAAAAJ&hl=fi&oi=ao) active 5 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/502631/134583 (TDMt: seen ~25 d ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/444210/134583 (nuclear corrections: seen ~25d ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/335064/134583 (OQS: not seen since account made)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/308930/134583 (PPs: not seen since account made)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202653/134583 (Parr/Yang f'l: seen 3 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/555282/134583 (LAPW: seen 2 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/542515/134583 (DFT: now (not then) active on MMSE)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/532071/134583 (Hirschfield: user active 3 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/531916/134583 (DFT: not active since making account)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525205/134583 (s,p,d orbitals: user active 3 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/513354/134583 (DFT:  [user](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=w0eP9esAAAAJ&hl=fi&oi=ao) active 5 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/508045/134583 (1-RDM:  [user](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=w0eP9esAAAAJ&hl=fi&oi=ao) active 5 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/418786/134583 (KS-DFT: not seen since opening)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267392/134583 (band structure: last seen 3 years ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160864/134583 (DFT: user last seen 3 months ago)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/404689/134583 (DOS: not seen since opening)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/462062/134583 (DFT: user not seen since opening)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176234/134583 (DFT: user active 10 days ago!)
- [h̶t̶t̶p̶s̶:̶/̶/̶p̶h̶y̶s̶i̶c̶s̶.̶s̶t̶a̶c̶k̶e̶x̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶q̶/̶3̶0̶4̶1̶4̶4̶/̶1̶3̶4̶5̶8̶3̶ ̶(̶A̶I̶M̶,̶ ̶D̶F̶T̶:̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶ ̶a̶c̶t̶i̶v̶e̶)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1667/5)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/483183/134583 (VASP: user seen 12 days ago!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/489253/134583 (DFT: user active every day!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/494645/134583 (KS-DFT: user seen 7 days ago!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/524710/134583 (TD-DFT: user seen 7 days ago!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/534927/134583 (TD-DFT: user active every day)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/543249/134583 (spin-polarized DFT: active every day!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/547591/134583 (DFT bands: user active every day!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136330/134583 (closed but ok: user active everyday!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/226374/134583 (fermions: user active every day!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/316392/134583 (KS-DFT: user active every day!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338272/134583 (DFT for crystal: user seen 6 days ago!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/381711/134583 (DFT: seen 3 days ago!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465172/134583 (DFT: user active every day!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/470426/134583 (HF/KS-DFT: user active every day!)
- [<s>https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/542754/134583 (Schroedinger eqn: active everyday!)</s>](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/does-the-schr%c3%b6dinger-equation-have-unique-solutions)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/562176/134583 (DOS of nanoribbon, active every day!)
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/543135/134583 (DFT: active 5 days ago, MMSE user)

#### Physics.SE, with condensed-matter tag, 0 upvoted or accepted answers:

- To do ([1254 questions fit these criteria!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/condensed-matter?tab=Unanswered))

#### Physics.SE, with solid-state-physics tag, 0 upvoted or accepted answers:

- To do ([826 questions fit these criteria!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solid-state-physics?tab=Unanswered))

#### Physics.SE, with schroedinger-equation tag, 0 upvoted or accepted answers:

- To do ([305 questions fit these criteria!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schroedinger-equation?tab=Unanswered))

#### Physics.SE, with semiconductor-physics tag, 0 upvoted or accepted answers:

- To do ([418 questions fit these criteria!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semiconductor-physics?tab=Unanswered))

#### Physics.SE, with materials-science tag, 0 upvoted or accepted answers:

- To do ([314 questions fit these criteria!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/material-science?tab=Unanswered))

#### Physics.SE, with computational-physics tag, 0 upvoted or accepted answers:

- To do ([396 questions fit these criteria!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-physics?tab=Unanswered))

#### Physics.SE, with materials-science tag, 0 upvoted or accepted answers:

- To do ([208 questions fit these criteria!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-chemistry?tab=Unanswered))

#### Physics.SE, with phonons tag, 0 upvoted or accepted answers:

- https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294877/134583

Comment: When you advertise your site, make sure to tell them to also delete the original question.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I suppose they (or we) could post a link to the new question in the comments. The same question can be asked on two different sites, except in special cases like Chemistry (I think) where there is a close reason associated with the question having an answer on a different site.

Comment: Cross posting is considered a terrible practice across the whole network and often results in closure of all questions. Do not encourage that please, there are users out there looking for these cases and flag them. If you must ask a question on two different sites, make sure you highlight that you want different answers and be very, very transparent about it (like in the first sentence of the question).

Comment: Also: there is no close reason for that associated on chemistry (or other sites). It is just something moderators warn each others about to not double the effort of their communities. Unfortunately there is not network-wide linking of questions (including duplicates) which would be quite beneficial for science sites.